# How to remove or substitute "and" from a BibTeX bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I would like to remove "and" from my bibliography,because this what I have now:

> C. Danti, M. Matteini, **and** A. Moles. Le Pitture murali: tecniche,
>   problemi, conservazione. Centro Di, 1990.

I would like to remove "and" or replace it with the proper conjunction in my languages (e.g. "e"). To get this:

> C. Danti, M. Matteini, A. Moles. Le Pitture murali: tecniche,
>   problemi, conservazione. Centro Di, 1990.

This, for example, is my `biblio.bib`file:

```
@book{danti1990pitture,
    Author = {Danti, C. and Matteini, M. and Moles, A.},
    Date-Added = {2013-11-25 16:52:18 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2013-11-25 16:52:18 +0000},
    Isbn = {9788870381962},
    Lccn = {91161506},
    Publisher = {Centro Di},
    Title = {Le Pitture murali: tecniche, problemi, conservazione},
    Url = {http://books.google.it/books?id=077qAAAAMAAJ},
    Year = {1990},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://books.google.it/books?id=077qAAAAMAAJ}}
```

This is my `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
I cite \cite{danti1990pitture} but I don't want the``and".
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What BibTeX style are you using? Can you post an MWE?

Comment: There are some solutions. In your case I recommend `babelbib`. However for more settings you should use `biblatex`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I used `babelbib`but the `and` is still there..

Comment: @GM: I provided an example. I hope it helps.

Comment: Do you want to remove the "and" in all entries, i.e., even if there are *exactly two* authors, or only if there are *three or more* authors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggest you can use `babelbib`. If you are using `babelbib` you have to use a supported bibliography style. In your case `babplain`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{biblio.bib}
@book{danti1990pitture,
    Author = {Danti, C. and Matteini, M. and Moles, A.},
    Date-Added = {2013-11-25 16:52:18 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2013-11-25 16:52:18 +0000},
    Isbn = {9788870381962},
    Lccn = {91161506},
    Publisher = {Centro Di},
    Title = {Le Pitture murali: tecniche, problemi, conservazione},
    Url = {http://books.google.it/books?id=077qAAAAMAAJ},
    Year = {1990},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://books.google.it/books?id=077qAAAAMAAJ}}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,italian]{book}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babelbib}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
I cite \cite{danti1990pitture} but I don't want the "and".
\bibliographystyle{babplain}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot, this works but now I've the url and some titles are all capitalized...

Comment: The field `url` is surrounded by `\btxurlfont` so you set it to `\def\btxurlfont#1{}`. The capitalised letters I can't recognise.

Comment: mmm how can I set \def\btulfont#1{} where can I put this command?

Comment: @GM: Somewhere in your header after loading `babelbib`. However in your comment you used a wrong spelling of the macro.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using the `plain` bibliography style, you could proceed along the following lines to replace the "and" conjunction with "e":

- Find the file `plain.bst` in your TeX distribution, make a copy, and name the copy, say, `myplain.bst`. (Do not edit an original file directly.)
- Open `myplain.bst` in your favorite text editor.
- Locate the two instances of `" and "` in the file. (In my copy, they occur on lines 201 and 480.)

  Change the `" and "` strings to `" e "`.
- Save the new style file, either in the same directory as where your `.tex` file is located or in a directory that's searched by your TeX distribution. Update the filename database as appropriate for your TeX distribution.
- Be sure to include the directive `\bibliographystyle{myplain}` from now on.

With these changes applied to `myplain.bst`, the following output results from re-running your MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
I cite \cite{danti1990pitture} but I don't want the ``and''.
\bibliographystyle{myplain}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me [this is myplain.bst file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9O7sxdAf2xjY1lZaHJXLU5FSGc/edit?usp=sharing) I've put it where my `.tex`file is and run`sudo -H mktexlsr` in terminal because I've texlive2013 but a bunch of errors came out when I compile pdfLatex so I've removed all the old files and live only `.tex, .bib` and `.bst`file run `BibTeX`and then `PdfLaTeX` twice and it worked. I write it here for the others user. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @GM - Thanks for this feedback. Glad you figured out that after switching to a new bibliography style, it's a good idea to blow away the `.aux` and other temporary files and to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more in order to adapt everything to the new system.

Answer (score 0):

for remove "and" add `%` to `bbl.and` in `FUNCTION {format.names}`, eg

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}{, f.}{, jj}"
      format.name$
      bib.name.font
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { "; " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal emphasize *
                }
                {
                  %bbl.and
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I've edited your post just to add some markup for nice formatting of the code.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good idea, to me it seems that the result will miss a comma in place of the missing "and". But I may be wrong. Can you show a test example, please?