# Language problems when building bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, babel

I'm having trouble making my bibliography. Between multiple authors it shows "and"  in stead of the  dutch "en". I've been searching  for solutions and most answers state this should do the job:

```
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}  
\bibliography{referenties}   
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

However, it  doesn't work, I'm still getting  "and" in my bibliography. The title "bibliography" did get translated to "bibliografie" though.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The answer is similar to the issue: [How to remove or substitute “and” from a BibTeX bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149292/how-to-remove-or-substitute-and-from-a-bibtex-bibliography)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: should this apply to the whole bibliography, or only particular entries.  if the whole bibliography, then @MarcoDaniel's pointer is a good one.

Comment: Yep,  thanks Marco. I forgot/didn't know I had  to add the babelbib package too.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider using `biblatex` this would be done automatically. To have the same type of bibliography, you would have to put this in your preamble:

```
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=none, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{referenties.bib}
```

and at the place you want your bibliography:

```
\print bibliography}
```

Biblatex makes it easier tu customise the formatting of your bibliography. Note that the default back-end for biblatex  is `biber`, which has the advantage to understand `utf8` .bib files and adds many possibilites to bibtex.