# Citations in two different languages for the same LaTeX document

Tags: natbib

I am writing a LaTeX document using overleaf for which I need to write in both french and english. I am using the `\citalp` function from the `natbib` package, which makes citations as follow:

- Smith, 1999. If 1 author
- Smith and Jones, 1999. If 2 authors.
- Smith et al., 1999. If more than 2 authors.

But when I am writing in french, i need the citation to be "Smith et Jones, 1999" for the two authors case, "et" standing for "and". But I still need to keep `\citalp` for english paragraphs.

Here is an example of what I have:

TeX file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\section{French section}

Let's say this is french text for which i need to cite "Smith et Jones, 1999" but sadly, the citealp function gives me this: \citealp{smith1999}

\section{English section}

This paragraph is written in English so using citealp is what i need:  \citealp{smith1999}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

test.bib

```
@article{smith1999,
    author = {Smith, A. and Jones, B.},
    title = {A very nice paper},
    journal = {Great Journal},
    year = {1999}
}
```

Comment: The `natbib` standard styles are solidly monolingual English. For multilingual BibTeX-based bibliographies I only know of [`babelbib`](https://ctan.org/pkg/babelbib) (not sure how well that plays with `natbib`). `biblatex` supports multilingual citations out of the box (but of course that would require going from a BibTeX-based approach to `biblatex`, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864).

Comment: An example use of  `babelbib` is shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149292/35864

Comment: Hrrmmm, some further (tentative) research suggests that `babelbib` may not support author-year citations... (But I found that `apacite`, which implements the bibliography and citation style of the 6th edition of the APA manual, has some multilingual support. Still I think the best way nowadays is `biblatex`. But I'm biased there.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have to absolutely use the `natbib`-package, I would recommend a rather painless switch to `biblatex` (with natbib=true). moewe is absolutely right here, this change will make your life so much easier.

There are a couple of things which have to be changed, like the removal of the small caps for names in French (see the comment in my MWE) and a couple of initials. This comes pretty close to `natbib` and will infinitely simplify your life.

I have tested the following minimal working example using overleaf. It worked out of the box:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Bibliography-Settings
\usepackage[
style=authoryear,giveninits=true,uniquename=init,natbib=true
]{biblatex}

% Remove small caps in the French version
\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\section{French section}
\selectlanguage{french}
Let's say this is french text for which i need to cite "Smith et Jones, 1999" but sadly, the citealp function gives me this: \citealp{smith1999}

\section{English section}

\selectlanguage{english}
This paragraph is written in English so using citealp is what i need: \citealp{smith1999}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image: Citations in different languages using biblatex]

Comment: +1 Though I would recommend going the slightly more painful way of not using `natbib=true,` at least for new documents and using the standard `biblatex` command name `\autocite` (`\cite`, `\parencite`, `\textcite` if required) instead.

Comment: True, I agree. It depends how far the document has come along. If it is feasible in a sensible amount of time, do exactly as @moewe has said.

Comment: Hey guys I am sorry for the delayed response. After struggling to switch from natbib to biblatex, it finally works perfectly. Thank you very much to both of you. Cheers.

Comment: @Smich7, no problem. Glad it worked out for you.